# Is it possible to add new items to the Charms Bar?

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

If you press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Windows 8, you will get the new UI element called the Charms Bar. It contains some useful links for sharing and searching:

[image: charms bar]

If you want to customize it, searching on internet will probably lead you to a third-party application like [this](http://www.vikitech.com/11109/customize-windows-8-charms-bar) or [this](http://www.guidingtech.com/10162/personalize-new-windows-8-charm-bar/). However, it seems that they will only allow you to set a new skin for the bar's buttons.

Is it actually possible to add a new button or remove any existing button from the Windows 8 Charms Bar?

Comment: I would like to pin my favorite apps there :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The charms bar was designed with only these in mind. There is no official way to add icons to the charms bar.

Comment: And with good reason. They're trying for consistency (for a change) across all editions of Windows 8.

Comment: They have been looking after such consistency by making their recent products less and less customizable (ribbons, charm bar, start menu, etc). This is why people should use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is not possible to do exactly what you desire with the Windows 8 Charms Bar, there is a degree of manipulation that can be achieved with it.

**My WCP CharmBar Customizer** is a free portable application that will help customize many aspects of the Windows 8 Charms Bar.

[image]

If at any time, you decide that you don’t like the changes anymore, you can restore default settings with only one click.

Download:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/My-WCP-CharmBar-Customizer.shtml