# Customize Windows 8 Charm Bar

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add new items to the Charms Bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/495667/is-it-possible-to-add-new-items-to-the-charms-bar)

Is there a way to customize the Charm Bar in Windows 8?

For example, I want to add shortcut for quicker access to folder/application, and/or remove the Share and Devices buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to edit the the shortcuts on the Charms Bar, though as ronalchn showed; you can customize the appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[My WCP Charmbar Customizer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/My-WCP-CharmBar-Customizer.shtml)**.

Using it, you can easily change the look of your charms bar:

[image]

To actually change the buttons, you might be able to use the **Edit UI File** feature to change the code (not sure how you can setup the action a button takes though):

[image]

Sources:

- http://www.guidingtech.com/10162/personalize-new-windows-8-charm-bar/
- http://www.vikitech.com/11109/customize-windows-8-charms-bar
- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/customize-windows-8-charms-bar-wcp-charmbar-customizer

Comment: Its not about to customize skins. Op wants to ad/remove the program from Charm Bar.

Comment: The Edit UI file method can easily remove buttons (just remove it in the UI file). I think there currently isn't a way to add a button though.

Comment: That's what the OP exactly needs. He also want to add a shortcut to the charm bar.

Comment: Just because I have not found a way to add a button, doesn't mean that my answer is not relevant.

Comment: and one of the things the OP wants to do is to "remove the Share and Devices buttons"