# Customizing the Windows 8 Charms Bar

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

I've read [the other threads here](https://superuser.com/questions/498812/customize-windows-8-charm-bar), and on other sites too. I have downloaded the CharmBar Customizer application, even thought it was no longer accessible from the original links. However, when I try to run it, I get an error (that I can ignore) and when the application loads, all icons are empty. If I click the "edit UI" button, I get what looks like an encrypted or compressed file rather than the plain-text file shown in the screenshots.

Of course, I didn't try to save or apply anything, however, something interesting occured.
I had previously tried StarDock's Decor8 that can change the color of the Charms bar (among other things), but removed it because it creates a running process rather than just modifying files. However, after starting the Charms Bar customizer, I got the blue charms bar I had set with Decor8 instead of the black one.

[image]

Now, for some specific questions :

1. Has anyone managed to use CharmBar Customizer in Windows 8 retail? (it was created for Consumer Preview)
2. Does someone know where the Charms Bar UI definitions file is stored, and it's name? I would like to backup it, then mess around with the app, or try to unpack it.
3. Is there any other way to customize the CharmsBar? (including hand editing some file, dll ressource or anything)